# how to join multiple select statement together

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one mastertable id Accessories CarColor variant values ( 1 863,862 6 2 5) etc (all id's are going in my mastertable ) and 5 other table like car color,variant etc  which has values

---

```
id   color
5    red
6    blue
3    green
```

I need value from  each child tables whose id = mastertable.id 
like

```
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(" select * from cartable where carcolor.id = mastertable.carcolor ") ; 
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(" select * from varianttable where variant.id = mastertable.variant ")  ; 
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand ("select * from accessoriestable where accessories.id = mastertable.accessories ") ;//
```

my question is how can i join all 5 select statements together 
    or any better solution for this ?

Comment: Please edit your question it is almost unreadable. The answer will be simple but you need to make it clear and right now I can even read it properly.

Comment: How do you want your results to be displayed? Best way is to use Joins

Comment: i need value from each child table whose id = mastertable.id

Comment: i have 5 column in my master table and 5 child table (one child table for each column of master table) which are joined with master table and i need value from each table whose id = mastertable.id

Comment: all id's are going in master table like 5 is id of color in master table  and in color table color   value is there where id = 5  same as with other tables  i hope u understand my question

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? DB2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you need this?

```
select * from mastertable
left join carcolortable on mastertable.carcolor=carcolortable.id
left join varianttable on mastertable.variant=varianttable.id
left join accessoriestable on mastertable.accessories=accessoriestable.id
```

If as you've described in the comment `mastertable.carcolor` (and others) contains a comma separated list of `Id`'s in `varchar` then it should be:

```
select * from mastertable
left join carcolortable on 
        ( ','+mastertable.carcolor+',' 
          LIKE 
          '%,'+CAST(carcolortable.id as varchar(100))+',%'
         )
left join varianttable on 
        ( ','+mastertable.variant+',' 
          LIKE 
          '%,'+CAST(varianttable.id as varchar(100))+',%'
         )

left join accessoriestable on 
        ( ','+mastertable.accessories+',' 
          LIKE 
          '%,'+CAST(accessoriestable.id as varchar(100))+',%'
         )
```

Comment: thanks valex for your help .. now only problem is  if multiple accessories are selected then they r getting stored in master table with coma separator like 789,786 and sql is generating error message

Comment: Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '863,862' to data type int.  it taking 863 and 862 as a single  char

Comment: I've added a query to the answer for this case

Comment: select * from apraautoDB.dbo.tbl_Apra_NewCar_Booking_Details
left join apraautoDB.dbo.tbl_Apra_NewCarColor on apraautoDB.dbo.tbl_Apra_NewCar_Booking_Details.CarColor= apraautoDB.dbo.tbl_Apra_NewCarColor.Id
left join apraautoDB.dbo.tbl_Apra_NewCar_Variant on apraautoDB.dbo.tbl_Apra_NewCar_Booking_Details.variantID= apraautoDB.dbo.tbl_Apra_NewCar_Variant.ID
left join apraautoDB.dbo.tbl_Accessories on (','+apraautoDB.dbo.tbl_Apra_NewCar_Booking_Details.Accessories +',' like '%,'+CAST( apraautoDB.dbo.tbl_Accessories.ID as  varchar(100))+',%' ) i m not getting name of accessories